# Component View not displaying data resolved from a promise

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I have a component called ProfileComponent that uses a service called ProfileService to retrieve its data. The ProfileService has a method called getProfile that returns a promise. In the then method, I assign the necessary profile data to a public property on the component called profile. The issue is that it seems that the view is not waiting for the promise to resolve to show the info in the view. It's just giving an error, "property undefined". I've looked at using [Page life Cycle Hooks](https://webcake.co/page-lifecycle-hooks-in-ionic-2/), but it didn't help with the problem.

**Profile Component**

```
import { Component , OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';

import { Profile } from './profile';
import { ProfileService } from './profile.service';

@Component({
    selector:'profile',
    templateUrl: 'build/profile/profile.component.html',
    providers: [ProfileService]
})
export class ProfileComponent{
    // public properties
    profile: Profile;

    constructor(private profileService: ProfileService){
        this.getProfile();
    }

    private getProfile(){
         this.profileService.getProfile()
         .then(data => {
             console.log(data); // I see the needed data here
             this.profile = data;
        });
    }
}
```

**Profile Service**

```
imports...
@Injectable()
export class ProfileService {

    profile: Profile = {
                "firstName": 'Chelsea',
                "lastName": 'Wilson',
                "phone": '713-567-0957',
                "email": 'julip@gmail.com',
                "authorizationCode":'1232839475234537',
                "agreementExpiration": new Date('12/31/2017'),
                "ESIID" : '123294734SDFDSSD23'
    };

    getProfile(){
        return Promise.resolve(this.profile);
    }
}
```

**Profile View**

```
<div class="main-nav-wrapper">
    <div class="main-nav-content brite-card">
        <h2 class="brite-card-header">Personal Details</h2>
        <div class="profile-item">
            <span class="profile-label">Name</span>
            <span class="profile-detail">{{profile.firstName}} {{profile.lastName}}</span>
        </div>
        <div class="profile-item">
            <span class="profile-label">Email</span>
            <span class="profile-detail">{{profile.email}}</span>
        </div>
        <div class="profile-item"> 
            <span class="profile-label">Phone Number</span>
            <span class="profile-detail">{{profile.phone}}</span>
        </div>
        <div class="profile-item">
            <span class="profile-label">Authorization Code</span>
            <span class="profile-detail">{{profile.authorizationCode}}</span>
        </div>
        <div class="profile-item">
            <span class="profile-label">Agreement Expiration Date</span>
            <span class="profile-detail">{{profile.agreementExpiration}}</span>
        </div>
        <div class="profile-item">
            <span class="profile-label">ESIID</span>
            <span class="profile-detail">{{profile.ESIID}}</span>
        </div>       
    </div>
</div>
```

**Error**

```
EXCEPTION: Error: Uncaught (in promise): EXCEPTION: Error in build/profile/profile.component.html:5:41
ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: TypeError: Cannot read property 'firstName' of null
```

**PS**

I have another component and service that works together, but I'm using `*ngFor` to show its info, so I think that the `*ngFor` is having an effect on the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a better way to handle this scenario. Please take a look at [this plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/E0t7x6?p=preview). Since you don't know when the data will be ready, you could do it like this:

1. Initialize the information you're going to show in your view, with empty data (in order to prevent errors in the view)

   ```
   private profile: Profile = {
               "firstName": '',
               "lastName": '',
               "phone": '',
               "email": ',
               "authorizationCode":'',
               "agreementExpiration": '',
               "ESIID" : ''
   };
   ```
2. Present a loading popup so the user knows that something is going on, and also to *disable* the view until the information is ready.
3. When the information is ready, dismiss the popup so the user can interact with the view.

Even though using nullable variables may work, you always need to think in terms of the users, and how to make things easier to understand for them. I wouldn't be happy to use an application that first shows me an empty view and then after a few seconds (and without letting me know anything) the view changes and displays information.

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

I think, you should fetch data from ProfileService inside **ngOnInit()** method. You need import { OnInit } from '@angular/core' and put class to implement it. ngOnInit() method will be processed before template is worked out (?). Most likely after your constructor is finished (Promise is still not worked out) template is shown and profile is still null. Hope this help. I am really new with Angular 2, so I am guessing.

Comment: When I placed `this.getProfile()` into `ngOnInit()` it still gives the same error.

Answer (score 0):

what you need is to create an empty object for `profile` property,

option 1:

```
   profile: Profile =  new Profile(); // Provided its a class.
```

option 2: 
If you may not instantiate Profile (is an interface), you may use nullable properties

```
  {{profile.firstName}}  -> {{profile?.firstName}}
```

Hope this helps!!

Comment: Option 2 worked! But is there any other work around besides this? How can I wait until the promise is resolved to render the view?

Comment: i guess you can not, once you are inside component,